# How to set metadata while compressing files using gzip?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting a static website on Amazon S3. It's basically a theme with all static files (HTML, CSS, JS & Image files)

Everything works fine. I've also activated Cloudfront. But the site is still sluggish and very slow while loading. So I wanted to gzip the content & started to follow this doc [Serving Compressed Files from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedS3)

But the part where I've to go to 2000+ files and update Metadata as "Content-Encoding" as "gzip" is too tedious and isn't practical for me.
Is there a way I can add this metadata while I compress the files using gzip.exe on my local system?

Or any other workaround?

Please guide me. I'm stuck. :(

Comment: Something's wrong if it's tedious. What programing language are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any programming language. I've 50+ HTML files, 1000+ JS and CSS files and a bunch of images. It's a theme.

Comment: The metadata would be updated in S3 if you upload a proper gzip file with a gzip file extension through the AWS console. But your bigger problem is that the links in your html files will not update based on whether or not your client's browser supports compression.  Maybe there's another way to speedup your pages?  Make your images smaller optimize js?

Comment: You're correct, @Edwin this looks too tedious. I've made all other possible measures. I'm thinking of hosting it on Apache and then configuring Apache easily with mod_deflate etc, set expiration headers etc. Looks like a better option.